# Do I have to sanitize value parameters in a QueryInterface::condition statement?

Tags: entities, 9

Do I need to sanitize `$userinput` in this code, or is it done by Drupal?

```php
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type','my_node_type')
  ->condition('field_myfield', $userinput)
  ->execute();
```

In my case, `$userinput` is a path parameter from the .routing.yml file.

If necessary, how do I sanitize it? I found [`RequestSanitizer::sanitize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Security!RequestSanitizer.php/function/RequestSanitizer::sanitize/9.3.x). Is that enough to protect against SQL injections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in [Writing secure code for Drupal / Use the database abstraction layer to avoid SQL injection attacks](https://www.drupal.org/docs/security-in-drupal/writing-secure-code-for-drupal#s-use-the-database-abstraction-layer-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks), it's not necessary to sanitize user input used in the `condition()` method, as long as the user input isn't used to select the operator to apply. This means that the code shown in the question is fine, but the following code is not.

```php
\Database::getConnection()
  ->select('table', 't')
  ->condition('t.field', $value, $userInput)
  ->execute();
```

What reported in that documentation is for the database classes, but it's also valid for the methods exposed from the instance returned by `\Drupal::entityQuery()`.